# Why do ALL of my git repositories suddenly show that everything has been deleted?

Tags: git

The files are THERE, git just tells me that they have been deleted from the repository. Could this be a Github problem?

I have navigated to my project folder that I haven't worked on in a couple of days, and like usual I run:

```
git status
```

However, instead of seeing 1 or 2 files, the status shows that all of my files have been deleted. Then, in "Untracked Files", it shows all of my files and directories in app root that need to be added.

I don't understand what has happened, but I am very worried that any work I did since the last commit is gone.

I opened the git log up with `git k`, and at very the top I see:

```
Local changes checked in to index but not committed.
```

Right below that I see:

```
master    remotes/origins/master
```

Note: This project goes against a github database.

Here is the output from the `git status` command:

```
➜  mcp5_mobile git:(master) ✗ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

deleted:    .gitignore
deleted:    .rspec
deleted:    Gemfile
deleted:    README
deleted:    README.md
deleted:    Rakefile
deleted:    app/assets/images/MSDS_icon_rgb.jpg
deleted:    app/assets/images/MSDS_icon_rgb.png
deleted:    app/assets/images/addtocart.gif
<Continues to list every single file in the app. Over 1,100 files.>

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

.gitignore
.rspec
Gemfile
README
README.md
Rakefile
app/
autotest/
colorpicker.css
config.ru
config/
db/
deploy/
doc/
eye.js
features/
layout.css
lib/
public/
sample.xml
script/
spec/
termios/
test/
vendor/
```

Comment: I don't think it is telling you they have been deleted from the repository. It's telling you they been removed from the _index_. Just add them back in.

Comment: Could you actually show the output of `git status` please?

Comment: Why would all of my stuff have been removed from the index in all of my projects?

Comment: Hard to say. Did you ever in your life say `git rm`? Do you synch this computer with another computer?

Comment: Did you give some kind of global command that deletes all files called `index`? :)

Comment: No. I don't even know how to do a global command. And I haven't done `git rm` either.

Comment: My indexes are present in all 3 projects.

Comment: Are you using some kind of third-party GUI git interface? (I'm still trying to guess what might have affected the `.git/index` files.)

Comment: Anyhow the important thing is that so far the evidence is that _only_ the `.git/index` files were affected. You haven't lost the repository or your previous commits etc., you haven't lost coordination with github, and you haven't lost any work.

Comment: No, I always use git at the command line. And I just went over all my commands from the last successful time I used git and there aren't any unusual commands.

Comment: That's why I asked about synch with another computer. When I synch from computer A to computer B, this can affect the `index` in the `.git` folder on computer B. But it doesn't matter as long as computer A is where the work gets done. - In any case it sounds as if whatever happened, happened outside git, so that is why I'm making this kind of suggestions.

Comment: Must have been a path issue. I was trying to install some gems the other day and had to do funny things with PATH, PKG_CONFIG_PATH, and C_INCLUDE_PATH to get some things to compile normally. Anyway, I rebooted my Mac and now everything looks normal. I can't understand what it could be, I'm using the same git executable, I just checked. Are there some supporting libraries that git uses on startup that I may have messed up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This strongly suggests that you (or something you invoked indirectly) deleted or at least renamed `.git/index`:<sup>1</sup>

```
$ ls
LICENSE.txt x.txt
$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
$ mv .git/index .git/xindex
$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    deleted:    LICENSE.txt
    deleted:    x.txt

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    LICENSE.txt
    x.txt

$ mv .git/xindex .git/index
$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

In the above, I recovered by putting the `index` file back, but if it's really gone you can rebuild it from the `HEAD` commit using `git reset`'s `--mixed` (default) mode:

```
$ rm .git/index
$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    deleted:    LICENSE.txt
    deleted:    x.txt

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    LICENSE.txt
    x.txt

$ git reset -- .
$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

[Aside: you don't need the `-- .` as those are also the default.  This was more to emphasize that we're resetting every path inside `.` that is in the `HEAD` commit.  Of course I'm using the default-to-`HEAD`-commit action by not specifying `HEAD` explicitly either...]

---

<sup>1</sup>Alternatively, perhaps something you did set the environment variable `GIT_INDEX` to point somewhere odd.  Git uses `.git/index` when `GIT_INDEX` is *not* set, so if something has set it, that would override the default.

Comment: Would it alternatively be sufficient for him to `add .`?

Comment: My index files are present in all 3 projects.

Comment: @matt: yes, although the result is different.  By building the index out of the `HEAD` commit you can then compare the index and the working directory to see if there is stuff that should be `git add`-ed (which you might maybe want to do piecemeal and in separate commits, for instance).  If you're just going to add stuff afterward then you might as well use the add up front though. :-)

Comment: Right, and this would cause `git diff` to show that his work is not lost and is in fact ready to be added.

Answer (score 1):

A git repository is completely local. Therefore it is definitively not a github issue.

`git status` compares three different things. Your HEAD commit, your index and your working tree.

In your case it seems that the files are present it your working tree and your in your HEAD commit but where removed from your index.

A normal `git diff` compares your working tree with your HEAD commit. - If this diff looks fine you can simply do `git add .` to write the content of your working tree to your index. Alternatively you could use `git reset` to write the content of your HEAD commit to you index.

If you are generally worried about losing uncommitted changes, you should commit more often. Uncommitted changes are generally bad, because git does not know anything about them and therefore cannot help with restoring them in case of strange accidents.

Answer (score 0):

Must have been a path issue. I was trying to install some gems the other day and had to do funny things with PATH, PKG_CONFIG_PATH, and C_INCLUDE_PATH to get some native libraries to compile. Anyway, I rebooted my Mac and now everything looks normal. I can't understand what it could be, I'm using the same git executable, I just checked. Are there some supporting libraries that git uses on startup that I may have messed up?

I will update the answer as soon as I get it figured out. If you know the answer, I will award it to you. Upvotes all around, I appreciate the rapid response of the SO community, this was a scary problem.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened here (on a Mac/Yosemite). After laptop was in sleep mode all night, all of my local repositories showed all files deleted and in need of being added. Even repositories I had not worked in for months. I rebooted my machine and presto. Everything okay.

RD

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?